# Why can't I use ls() in a drake R plan?

Tags: r, environment-variables, drake-r-package

I'm trying to list all objects/variables/dataframes in a `drake` plan's environment that match a certain condition. However, when I try to use `ls()` for this, I'm returned an error.

How could I do this instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drake` childproofs the calling environment of `make()` and maintains a formal hierarchy of environments for actually evaluating code. This behavior is mostly a safeguard against side effects that could violate its functional programming assumptions (e.g. commands act like pure functions and targets are immutable). You can access `drake`'s environments with the [`drake_envir()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/drake/reference/drake_envir.html) function. Unless you are using [dynamic branching](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/dynamic.html), you probably want `ls(envir = drake_envir(which = "targets"))`.